# showing an error in my accountModel in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a model class for account of person, where i want to assing transactions to empty array..

i have assigned like this.transactions=[],

here is my modelclass

```
class AccountModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  DateTime createdOn;
  List<TransactionModel> transactions;
  bool isLocked;
  double payTotal;
  double receiveTotal;
  double balance;
  TransactionModel? lastEntry;


  AccountModel(
      {
required this.id, required this.name,
  this.transactions= [],// this is showing an error


 this.isLocked=false,
        this.balance=0,
        required this.createdOn,
        this.lastEntry,
        this.payTotal=0,
        this.receiveTotal=0,

      });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says exactly what's wrong.

```
The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
```

To solve make it a constant by writing const in front of it:

```
this.transactions = const []
```

EDIT:

As you have found out, a const list is unmodifiable so it's not really desired to have. I see two options to solve this. The first is to not make it part of the constructor at all and always initialize it with `[]` so like

```
class AccountModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  DateTime createdOn;
  List<TransactionModel> transactions = [];
  bool isLocked;
  double payTotal;
  double receiveTotal;
  double balance;
  TransactionModel? lastEntry;

  AccountModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    this.isLocked = false,
    this.balance = 0,
    required this.createdOn,
    this.lastEntry,
    this.payTotal = 0,
    this.receiveTotal = 0,
  });
}
```

If you really need it to be part of the constructor you could do this:

```
class AccountModel {
  String id;
  String name;
  DateTime createdOn;
  List<TransactionModel> transactions = [];
  bool isLocked;
  double payTotal;
  double receiveTotal;
  double balance;
  TransactionModel? lastEntry;

  AccountModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    List<TransactionModel>? transactions,
    this.isLocked = false,
    this.balance = 0,
    required this.createdOn,
    this.lastEntry,
    this.payTotal = 0,
    this.receiveTotal = 0,
  }) {
    if (transactions != null) this.transactions = transactions;
  }
}
```

Comment: i corrected with const...but later while adding record in it..its showing an error Cannot add to an unmodifiable list

Answer (score 0):

Here is `List<TransactionModel> transactions;`. Not `dynamic` type. You assigned with `dynamic` empty list. Can initialize with `TransactionModel` object.